How to mock interaction from method outside of Spec in Spock
I have a mocked object
userService = Mock()

and a mocked interaction
userService.test("test") >> "result"

How can I define this interaction in another class/method ?
Maybe >> can be replaced with some utility method ?
is it possible in Spock ?

Why would you? Can you please explain your rationale and the concrete use case? You must have a very compelling reason to make your specification less readable on purpose.
